# Help with css selector for jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this wordpress blog that has many pages with subpages that dropdown on hover.... the thing is, I dont want the pages that you hover to link to anything unless they dont have any ul with many anchors inside so just the subpages will have a href different than "#"
So basically Im hacking my way through this with some simple javascript.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#menus li > a").attr("href","#");
 });
```

This is selecting every a.. and I dont want that... I just want the anchors that are main pages, not subpages... heres the html so maybe you can think of a better way to select this.

Ill explain first

the structure is
an ul with many li that have an anchor inside
if the li also has a ul inside then those are subpages that will appear on hover.
hence the initial anchor should have href="#"
if there is no ul inside the li then the li a should keep its href.

```
    <ul id="menus">
      <li>
        <a href="somelink">Main Page</a> //href should be changed to #
        <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="somelink2/">Subpage1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="somelink3">Subpage2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="somelink">MainPage-with-no-subpages</a> //href should not be changed
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="somelink4">MainPage</a> //href should be changed to #
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="somelink5">Subpage</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="somelink6">Subpage</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#menus li > ul").siblings('a').attr("href","#");
});
```

Comment: Ignore whatever I said in my answer.  I did not read your question correctly.  Reigel is absoutely correct.

Comment: ` if there is no ul inside the li then the li a should keep its href.`, so, my approach is to find the ul... then change the href of `<a>`... if no ul, href of `<a>` remains....

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#menus li:has(ul) > a").attr("href","#");
}
```

Comment: using a non-standard selector like `:not`, `:has`, etc... is slow... as much as possible, try not using them...

Comment: I'm aware there's an overhead but I was of the impression it's no more slow than traversing up and then back down the DOM like the other answers? Correct me if I'm wrong...